# css right:5% not of parent element but % of the window's width

Tags: html, css, positioning

I built a slider with 8 different pictures.
On each picture, I wrote a caption.

I'm trying to set this caption with the css code :

```
.tp-caption{right:5%}
```

My ".tp-caption" div is out of my screen.
I read that the 5% are relative to the parent element properties.

And in my case the parent element is my picture wich is larger than my window's width (picure is centered)

Do you know if I can specify 5% of my window screen ?

I tried with margin-right, float:right too ... but it's always the same problem

thank you for your help

Comment: Is your .tp-caption div positioned absolute?

Comment: Can you share the full code or maybe create a fiddle of your code using "http://fiddle.jshell.net/"? That will be more helpful!!!

Comment: The percentages (%) are relative to the parent element's width, if and only if the parent element is positioned! Meaning it needs to have either a position of "absolute", "relative" or "fixed".

Answer (score 1):

The `right` property is applied to positioned elements only, as stated on the [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right)

So, for `right` to be effective, your caption element would have to contain one of the `position`'s values, like `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

It's true, the `right` offset will be relative to the element's parent. if you want it to be relative to the window's viewport, you should use then the `position: fixed` on the element, that removes the element from the natural flow of the document, and makes it subject only to the viewport.